# Suspend Main Thread, Execute some Callbacks, and then resume Main Thread

Tags: c#

I need to do somethings, execute some callbacks events, and then resume my routine. I'm using a Win Forms Application... I write you a little example.

```
 void Do()   // On main Thread
    {
         DoPartOne();

         // Her i want to execute the callbacks events... and then execute 
        //parttwo

         DoPartTwo();
    }

    void DoPartOne() // during this method i send commands to my connected service
    {
         StaticClass.Property = null;
    }

    void DoPartTwo() 
    {
         StaticClass.Property = something...
    }

    void MyCallBackOnEvent(MyEvent)
    {
       if(StaticClass.Property == null)
           DoThis();
       else
           DoThat();
    }
```

During Party One my Client send a command to my connected Service and it response me with some variable numbers of events.... I need to execute callbacks first of my PartTwo() method, but i fix that callback execute it when i finish the Do() method. Do you suggest me any other implementations?

Comment: Some  more realistic sample could help to clarify what you are asking... Also while [edit] the question provide info on what type of project you have (console/winforms/ASP.Net/something else).

Comment: Lets see if I understand this right. You want to call PartOne first, then PartTwo and only process events fired in PartOne once PartTwo is finished? Or once PartTwo is called?

Comment: i want to process events fineshed PartOne and before start PartTwo..

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! Given your explanation, could you simply call `DoPartOne` then call `MyCallBackOnEvent` and then finally call `DoPartTwo`? If not, why not?

Comment: I can not call MyCallbackOnEvent because is my connected service to call that.

Answer (score -1):

Do your action, then wait for a variable to become true:

```
while(!workIsDone)
{
   Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Then in your event, set the variable in your event, like so:

```
void MyCallBackOnEvent(MyEvent)
{  

    // Event has fired, so we can set workIsDone to true and then the main thread will stop the while loop, and continue normally.

    workIsDone = true;
}
```

Comment: that's not possibile.. when i put in sleep the mainthread it doesn't execute any instruction...